# How JS evaluates the expression ({...}).objMethod()?

Tags: javascript, object, expression, iife, javascript-scope

From my limited knowledge of how expression are evaluated in JS, in the code below, I know that parenthesis makes JS engine evaluates whatever is inside the parenthesis, as an expression `({..})` so `({..})` this will evaluate to the object `{...}` being returned  to the global scope (in this case, << *Am I right? pls correct me if not*) or whatever the scope the expression is in.

But what I don't understand is how the greet function `({...}).greet()` gets evaluated in the scope/context of the returned object from the expression `({..})`. Generally at-least I would assign the returned value of the expression to a variable/reference to the returned obj and then call the greet() method of that obj, as in

```
var x = ({...})
x.greet()
```

then, how the following code is evaluated.

```
({
  name: "John Doe",
  data: {
    message: "Hello World"
  },
  greet: function(){
    console.log("I am " + this.name);
    console.log("I have a message for you: " + this.data.message);
  }
}).greet();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just how you'd expect, it's just evaluating the object, then calling the `greet` method on it. It's like this:

```
console.log({ foo: 1 }.foo);
```

Except with a method. Also note that the parentheses are optional in the statement above, but are required in your question.

Comment: As u say, just evaluating the object, then calling the greet method on it, Now, we actually assign a variable/name to reference the returned object and then call the method via that variable, `myObj.greet()`, but here no reference/name is assigned.

Does JS dynamically assign a hidden name/memory address to the returned obj so that the called method knows about its context.

Also, how to access returned obj without assigning it to a variable i.e. `var obj = ({...})`

BTW, your example without the parentheses doesnt work. Chrome console throws `Uncaught syntaxError: unexpected token .`

Comment: Works fine for me @appu.